# phpmyadmin configuration on zend server community edition

Tags: zend

hi i am new to zend and i installed zend server in my local machine, i found phpmyadmin on my instalation directory and i copied it on htdocs. while running http://localhost/phpmyadmin  it appears login page and when i enter username and password it does not redirects to the main page. instead it gives "internal server error" thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `http://localhost:YOURZENDSERVERPORT/phpmyadmin` as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mysqlserver is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

The issue would be a regular MySQL permission issue.  Zend Server should not impact the authentication mechanism in there.